# Force XML character entities into XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, dom, xmldocument

I have some XML that looks like this:

```
<abc x="{"></abc>
```

I want to force XmlDocument to use the XML character entities of the brackets, ie:

```
<abc x="&#123;"></abc>
```

MSDN says this:

> In order to assign an attribute value
>   that contains entity references, the
>   user must create an XmlAttribute node
>   plus any XmlText and
>   XmlEntityReference nodes, build the
>   appropriate subtree and use
>   SetAttributeNode to assign it as the
>   value of an attribute.

[CreateEntityReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createentityreference.aspx) sounded promising, so I tried this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<abc />");
XmlAttribute x = doc.CreateAttribute("x");
x.AppendChild(doc.CreateEntityReference("#123"));
doc.DocumentElement.Attributes.Append(x);
```

And I get the exception `Cannot create an 'EntityReference' node with a name starting with '#'.`

Any reason why CreateEntityReference doesn't like the '#' - and more importantly how can I get the character entity into XmlDocument's XML?  Is it even possible?  I'm hoping to avoid string manipulation of the OuterXml...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mostly out of luck.

First off, what you're dealing with are called Character References, which is why CreateEntityReference fails. The sole reason for a character reference to exist is to provide access to characters that would be illegal in a given context or otherwise difficult to create.

> Definition: A character reference
> refers to a specific character in the
> ISO/IEC 10646 character set, for
> example one not directly accessible
> from available input devices.

([See section 4.1 of the XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-references))

When an XML processor encounters a character reference, if it is referenced in the value of an attribute (that is, if the `&#xxx` format is used inside an attribute), it is set to "Included" which means its value is looked up and the text is replaced.

> The string "`AT&amp;T;`" expands to "
> `AT&T;`" and the remaining ampersand is
> not recognized as an entity-reference
> delimiter

([See section 4.4 of the XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#entproc))

This is baked into the XML spec and the Microsoft XML stack is doing what it's required to do: process character references.

The best I can see you doing is to take a peek at these old XML.com articles, one of which uses XSL to disable output escaping so `&amp;#123;` would turn into `&#123;` in the output.
http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/03/14/trxml10.html

```
<!DOCTYPE stylesheet [
<!ENTITY ntilde 
"<xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&amp;ntilde;</xsl:text>">
]>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     version="1.0">

  <xsl:output doctype-system="testOut.dtd"/>

  <xsl:template match="test">
    <testOut>
      The Spanish word for "Spain" is "Espa&ntilde;a".
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </testOut>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this one which uses XSL to convert specific character references into other text sequences (to accomplish the same goal as the previous link).
http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1426

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="2.0">

  <xsl:output use-character-maps="cm1"/>

  <xsl:character-map name="cm1">
    <xsl:output-character character="&#160;" string="&amp;nbsp;"/>   
    <xsl:output-character character="&#233;" string="&amp;233;"/> <!-- é -->
    <xsl:output-character character="ô" string="&amp;#244;"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="&#8212;" string="--"/>
  </xsl:character-map>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: fantastic answer.  I had some feeling in the back of my mind that the "{" will never be internally represented as a &#123;, so the XmlDocument won't "hold onto" that representation.

Answer (score 0):

You should always manipulate your strings with the preceding @ like so @"My /?.,<> STRING". I don't know if that will solve your issue though.
I would approach the problem using XmlNode class from the XmlDocument. You can use the Attributes property and it'll be way easier. Check it out here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.attributes.aspx

Comment: Part of the problem is that setting the attribute to "&#123;" will result in XML that looks like "&amp;#123;". I'm trying to force XmlDocument to use the entity I want - but not having much luck.