# XMLDocument messing up character references

Tags: c#, xmldocument

File in: `compute = "...page.&#xD;o When you use the &#x201C;Create Form&#x201D; function ..."`

Do...

```
FileStream outfs = new FileStream(tempOutXmlFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,
                               FileShare.ReadWrite);

XMLDocument.Load(outfs)
```

File After Loading: `compute = "...page.&#xD;o When you use the "Create Form" function ..."`

When it comes time to write out the file again, I use

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(tempOutXmlFileName, false, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")))
            { //(The original file is ISO-8859-1 encoding.)

                writer.NewLine = "\n";
                xmlOut.Save(writer);
            }
```

and it doesn't seem to know not to write the `"`s directly, which is what I'd expect. Ideally I'd like to not have XMLDocument convert them, but if there's something I can do when writing it out, that would be okay, too.

Surely somebody has encountered problems like this before?  I was able to work around it a little before by doing 100% byte operations, but I'd like not to do that here since I need the XML document traversal functions.

Ideas? Suggestions?

Thank you.

**Resolution:**

I ended up just doing a find/replace.  Not pretty, but it does the job and I have some leeway with efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you want to do is going to be difficult.  This is the intended behavior.  As far as the actual information in the XML, there is no difference - it's just a detail of serialization.

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664913/force-xml-character-entities-into-xmldocument); it's good and addresses your question.

Why is it important to write out the quotation marks as entities?

Comment: The outputted xml must be used by another program and as-is its unable to parse the document accurately.

Comment: Maybe it's just me but the link in "answer" just points back to this question. Where was it intended to go?

Comment: Sorry, fixed the link.  

Is the resulting document actually not well-formed, or is it an issue with the receiving program?

Comment: Ah. I found that link before I posted here.  I can't change the pre-state of the documents, though.  As I understood the answer, I would need to do that.  Maybe I'll experiment with a find/replace on the stream before I load it as an XMLDocument.

Comment: The XML itself is well formed, but it turns out something like `<custom: popUp xfdl:compute = " viewer.MessageBox('o Here are some words: "Some words" and they are pretty.) " />`  When the viewer tries to load the document in gets confused by the nested quotation marks, hence the need to maintain the character references.

Comment: That's interesting.  If the XML is actually being serialized like you just put above, then that isn't well-formed.  Double quotes inside a double-quote-surrounded attribute do need to be stored as entities.  As far as changing it, you could also potentially manipulate the stream you're saving it to as well...

Comment: Ah, I'm mistaken then--not well-formed.  I was only thinking of the <> tags and not the attributes. I've toyed with how I might manipulate the outstream, but I would have to run some sort validation on the output just to figure out where the problem was, and then even more to ensure I replace the quotations with the proper codes... unless something else comes to mind?  I hope to experiment with the find/replace idea before loading it tomorrow.